# How do I get VcXsrv working with WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed VcXsrv and configured the DISPLAY variable, however, with VcXsrv running, I cannot get anything to connect to it.  For example:

```
a@HOME:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:0.0
a@HOME:~$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
a@HOME:~$
```

VcXsrv is enabled in windows firewall:

[image: Firewall]

I'm quite new to linux and Ubuntu so it is possible I am missing something obvious.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  What I am trying to achieve is simple: I want to run qemu from WSL with the graphical interface.  Thanks.

Comment: Try `:0.0` without the localhost

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answer, I was able to solve it by doing:

```
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
```

Note:

Using: `DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0`

While:
`echo $DISPLAY`

I've got:
`<my_gateway_IP>:0.0.`

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
```